# Copying the Image to Application Folder

Tags: java, swing

I have to copy the chosen image to the application folder. The image will be chosen by clicking the button.  Here is the code (ActionListener) for that Button

```
imageButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String outPath = new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath();
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File pic = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        String inPath = pic.getPath();
        try {
            Utils.copyFile(inPath, outPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

The method copyFile is this:

```
public static void copyFile(String inPath, String outPath) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File(inPath));
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath));

    int c;
    while((c=fis.read())!=-1)
    {
    fos.write(c);
    }
}
```

It gives "File not Found Exception" in Blue and in red color it shows "Access is Denied" when i select the image. I am not sure where the problem is there in my code.

Comment: `It gives` What gives? Your application? Where is that code? For better help sooner, consider providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Println the `outpath` see what it actually is.. and println the `inpath`... also you might still need to do... `if(!file.exsists()) file.createNewFile();`

Comment: @3Kings Actually i have printed both inPath and outPath and these are exactly the correct. but still cant find the problem.

Comment: @copeg When i compile my project it gives error on console

Comment: They can't be correct. outPath is the path of the current directory. You can't write into a directory. outPath should be the path of a file. Also, your copy method is extremely inefficient. Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: @JBNizet okay i got it but i still have one confusion. My app will run on the computer of Customer. So how would i be sure about the outPath that will exist in that computer.

Comment: It depends on what your application is supposed to do. All I know about it is that the user already has an image, that you're asking him/her to open that image, and that you're copying it somewhere else. But I have no clue on why your application does that. What's the point of copying the image elsewhere?

Comment: @JBZinet the actual purpose is to copy save the image to Database